# How to check whether the element is visible inside the Foreach loop in Galen?

Tags: javascript, galen

I am trying to check whether the element is visible or not, if it is visible then only check the UI property but the below command is giving an error "Exception is com.galenframework.parser.SyntaxException: JavaScript error inside statement"

```
@forEach [stats_count-*] as itemName, index as i
   @if ${isVisible("stats_count-"+{index})}
       ${itemName}:
            height 30 to 35 px
            width 35 to 45 px
            css font-size is "16px"
            css font-family contains "NeoRegular"
            css color is "rgba(82, 82, 82, 1)"
```

I tried below code as well, though it does not gives an error but it skips all the visible elements as well.

```
@if ${isVisible("stats_count-*")}
```

Any thing I am missing ?

Comment: I don't really know what galen is, however you can just check the visibility css value of the element. I'm pretty sure there's no isVisible method in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Posting the answer here if someone else faces the issue.

```
@forEach [mobile_text-*] as itemName, index as i
    @if ${isVisible(itemName)}
      ${itemName}:
```